# How can I append a new div to the last div with the same class name?

Tags: php, jquery

All my div blocks use the same class name and I need to append a new div block after a file upload has completed. The way I'm doing it now appends a new block to every existing block.  Here is my test code:

HTML:

```
<div class="img_container" id="img1">EXISTING BLOCK</div>'
<div class="img_container" id="img2">EXISTING BLOCK</div>'
```

JQuery:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $newdiv = $('<div class="img_container" id="img3">NEW BLOCK</div>');

    $('.img_container').append($newdiv);
})
```

I've also tried appending to the body tag but the new div never appears.  Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.img_container:last').after($newdiv) // should do the trick
```